# perl regex to bypass special characters

Tags: regex, perl

I am getting below error while executing this script

```
 $perl slaveScript.pl 
 Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^al4odb++ <-- HERE $/ at     slaveScript.pl line 104, <IFH> line 333.
```

code snippet is

```
    if(grep(/^$feat$/, @feature))
```

and the $feat value was al4odb++ some how it was getting greeping this value into the array @feature.

i am stuck here and searching for solution to skip this issue

Comment: @quentin I was literally clicking the submit button with my pretty long answer... :P

Comment: @simbabque — You can always put it on the original question … if it is better than the answers it has already.

Comment: @Quentin it was pretty much the same. There's not much else to say here. I should search and hammer more often.

Comment: @simbabque: I know, it's a pain right? The idea is to sanction the OP by preventing them from getting any solutions, but it often backfires and leaves the OP with just what they needed while wasting many people's time writing a response.

Comment: What version of Perl are you using. Since Perl 5.10, `++` is a possessive quantifier which doesn't produce a regex error with `(?^:^al4odb++$)`. Before all the mind readers showed up, it should have been asked _why are you getting this error not related to your code_ ??

Comment: @sln You answered your own question: the OP is using perl < 5.10. I get the same error that they posted with 5.8.8.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - It's hard to believe anybody uses < 5.10. There is really not that much difference except in the regex.

Comment: @sln Why is that hard to believe? [I see questions on SO all the time from people who explicitly say they're using 5.8.8.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[perl]%205.8.8%20is%3aq) Don't underestimate the number of companies still using ancient software (for a wide variety of stupid reasons).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Yeah, I used to work for companies like that. They invest so heavily in _unit test_ (or have none is more likely) it makes their pea brain managers head's explode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately i found this in web, i replace my code with below code snippet

```
if(grep(/^\Q$feat\E$/, @feature))
```

which solved my issue.

thought to post such question so that others also find the solution easily

[solution is here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=291766)

Comment: It's never too late to actually read about Perl Regular Expressions.